# How to redirect nested linux command output

Tags: linux, command-line

I kind of want to achieve something like this:
`time (curl -s $url > /dev/null) >> out.txt`
while the **curl** output will be deleted and I save the output of the **time**

Comment: Note that >> does not redirect the error stream, but time writes to the error stream.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{ time curl -s &url ;} 2>> out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`curl` provides an option to specify the output:

```
   -o, --output <file>
          Write output to <file> instead of stdout. If you are using {} or
          [] to fetch multiple documents, you can use '#'  followed  by  a
          number  in  the <file> specifier. That variable will be replaced
          with the current string for the URL being fetched. Like in:
```

Make use of that, and say:

```
time curl -s $url -o /dev/null >> out.txt
```